# dynamically creating table in sql database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

how can i create a table dynamically in the database which is already created.i want the table be created when a button is clicked.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a `CREATE TABLE` statement, making sure to escape all table and field names with `[...]`, and use a `SqlCommand` to execute it.